# Expect if condition with ssh password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I am currently trying to create a script with error handling.

Basically the script tests the ssh connection with this command :
`ssh -o BatchMode=yes $machine uname -a`

There is 3 potential situation that i want to handle :

1. SSH works just fine without password
2. SSH is blocked because the machine isn't in the `known_hosts` file in `.ssh`
3. SSH is blocked because the machine isn't in the `known_hosts` file in `.ssh` **AND** it requires a password to continue (which means the `id_rsa.pub` isn't in the `authorized_keys` file in `.ssh`

I have on main script that is calling an expect script here is what the main script looks like :

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes ${machine} uname -a &> temp-file.txt 2>&1
# Here we test the ssh connection just once and we store the output of the command in a temp file

if [ $? -eq 255 ]
# If the ssh didn't work

then

   if grep -q "Host key verification failed." temp-file.txt
   # If the error message is "Host key verification failed."

   then
      expect script-expect-knownhosts.exp ${machine} 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

And here is the `script-expect-knownhosts.exp` file in which i tried to make a condition :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set machine [lindex $argv 0]
# Here we state that the first argument used with the command will be the $machine variable

set prompt "#|%|>|\$ $"

set timeout 60

spawn ssh $machine
# We do a ssh on the machine

set prompt "#|%|>|\$ $"

expect { 

    "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? "  {send "yes\r";exp_continue} 
     # If he asks for a yes/no answer, then answer yes to add the machine to the known_hosts file

    -exact "Password: " {send -- "^C";exp_continue}
     # If he asks for a password, then send a CTRL + C

    -re $prompt {send "exit\r";exp_continue}
     # If the prompt shows up (if after the yes/no question, we don't need to put a password in) then type exit

}
```

So here is what happens when i execute the expect script with a machine in case number 2 (works just fine):

```
spawn ssh machine
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
machine:~ # exit
deconnection
Connection to machine closed.
```

And here is what happens when i execute the expect script with a machine in case number 3 :

```
spawn ssh machine
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Password:
```

And it stays stuck on Password until i manually do a CTRL + C

Comment: What is the question/error?

Comment: Sending "^C" will not produce a control-c, you need to write the ASCII code - "\x03" .

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your answers, i edited the post, i indeed forgot to write the question/error.

Also i tried replacing "^C" with "\x03" and it gives the exact same result for both of the cases

Comment: UPDATE : Removing "expect eof" removes the error in case number 2, but the real problem is that i can't send a CTRL + C when the Password is required and that is what i need to resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases 2 and 3 you don't need `exp_continue` because you are stopping the connection process.

For case 2, I don't think you really want to send a control-C.  When you do this interactively, typing control-C has the effect of sending a signal to kill the process you are interacting with.  What you really want is to stop the `ssh` process, so instead of `send -- "^C";exp_continue` you should just do `close`.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, thank you for your answer